# Is there a way to find feature importance per each prediction?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I know that

```
X_train = [

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
[13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
.....

]

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
probas_test = clf.predict_proba(y_)

clf.feature_importances_
```

will give the feature importance of a classifier that has been fit to the Training dataset.

But, How can I use this trained model to give a similar kind of importance value when predicting against unseen data per *INDIVIDUAL ROW*.
For example let,

```
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2]
 
clf.predict_proba(X)
```

Then is there a way to get the importance of each column, which is specific to this particular row rather than considering a set of rows.
Something like

```
clf.feature_importances_individual_
```

or even somthing like

```
clf.get_feature_importance(X)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're using the feature importance method of a tree based model in `sklearn`. This is computed by taking into account all the instances of the training set. Hence, you cannot derive the feature importance for a tree on a row base.

The same occurs if you consider for example logistic or linear regression models: the coefficients (which might be considered as a proxy of the feature importance) are derived starting from all the instances used for training the model.

To move on a row base, my advice would be to use [shap](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) values, which repeatedly proved to be a great tool to interpret model results.